# CSS: make div boxes in image relative to image size

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm displaying a list of thumbnails that can be zoomed in and out. On top of each thumbnail, I need to place text that is selectable by the user (I'm using jQuery UI Selectable for this).

Here what I have (complete code on http://jsfiddle.net/jEkaa/2/):

```
<ul>
    <li class="selectable">
        <a href="">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" width="400" height="400"></img>
        </a>
        <div style="position: absolute; width: 3.93em; height: 1.86em; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; left: 6.81em; top: 11.57em;">400</div>
        <div style="position: absolute; width: 1.13em; height: 1.86em; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; left: 11.57em; top: 11.57em;">x</div>
        <div style="position: absolute; width: 3.93em; height: 1.86em; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; left: 13.43em; top: 11.57em;">400</div>
    </li>
<ul>
```

When the image size changes, what do I need to do in order to keep the div boxes in the same relative position (so that jQuery UI Selectable still works)? Do I need a container around the image and div that specifies some relative measurement value?

I'm adding the divs to an existing application. So, the placement of the divs is not set in stone; perhaps they should go in the anchor tag?

Comment: in jsFiddle you don't need to add your own `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Just select it from the menu on the left. I'm also not seeing the image resizing, have you included that in the mockup?

Comment: @david, @StackOverflowNewbie, [revised demo with the in-html links/scripts removed to the side-bar](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jEkaa/3/). Also, I'm not seeing any images. Which **does** make it tricky to advise you on an image-resizing based question.

Comment: @david, thanks for the jsFiddle tip. No, I have not added zooming function. In the real application, it's done by Ajax. The image source is replaced and the height and width values are updated.

Comment: The image is there, in the top corner, very small...

Comment: @David: to resize the image, I am manually doing what the actual application does via Ajax. Basically, change the image source and height/width. So `<img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" width="400px" height="400px" />` becomes `<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" width="200px" height="200px" />` when zoomed out by 50%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to position and size using percentages for the text labels, you can simply add a container div and adjust it's size when you adjust the size of the image:

http://jsfiddle.net/ym4gE/4/